# Understanding git gc --auto

Tags: git, garbage-collection

I'm experimenting with fairly aggressive auto gc in Git, mainly for packing purposes. In my repos if I do `git config --list` I have setup

```
...
gc.auto=250
gc.autopacklimit=30
...
```

If I do `git count-objects -v` I get

```
count: 376
size: 1251
in-pack: 2776
packs: 1
size-pack: 2697
prune-packable: 0
garbage: 0
```

But `git gc --auto` doesn't change these figures, nothing is being packed! shouldn't the loose objects get packed since I'm 126 objects over the gc.auto limit?

Comment: Perhaps a significant portion of those loose objects are in fact dangling? Try `git gc --auto --prune=now` and/or `git fsck --full`...

Comment: `git fsck --dangling` gives just 3 dandling commits. I haven't done any rebasing or anything fancy since my last full GC. I tried `--auto --prune=now`, no change

Comment: I wonder how many trees and blobs are unique to those 3 commits (i.e. not referenced by any other non-dangling commit). Can't think of an easy way to figure that out, though, other than a lot of `git cat-file ...` and `git ls-tree ...` shenanigans...

Comment: `fsck --dangling` gives 13 dangling blobs, 3 commits and 1 tag. My usage recently has been very linear, I can't believe that's the problem. I now have 402 loose objects

Answer (score 47, accepted):

One of the main points of `gc --auto` is that it should be very quick, so other commands can frequently call it “just in case”. To achieve that, the object count is only guessed. As `git help config` says under `gc.auto`:

> When there are **approximately** more than this many loose objects in the repository […]

Looking at the code ([`too_many_loose_objects()` in `buildin/gc.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8858448bb49332d353febc078ce4a3abcc962efe/builtin/gc.c#L146)), here’s what happens:

1. The gc.auto is divided by 256 and rounded up
2. The folder that contains all the objects that start with `17` is opened
3. It is checked if the folder contains more objects than the result of step 1

This works fine, since SHA-1 is evenly distributed, so “all the objects that start with X” is representative for the whole set. But of course this only works for a big big amount of objects. To lazy to do the maths, I would guess at least >3000. With 6700 (the default value of `gc.auto`), this should already work quite reliably.

The core question for me is why you need such a low setting and whether it is important that this really runs at 250 objects. With a setting of 250, `gc` will run as soon as you have 2 loose objects that start with `17`. The chance that this happens is `> 80%` for 600 objects and `> 90%` for 800 objects.

**Update:** Couldn’t help it – had to do the math :). I was wondering how well that estimation system would work. Here’s a plot of the results. For any given `gc.auto`, how high is the probability that `gc` will start when there are `gc.auto` (red) / `gc.auto * 1.1` (green) / `gc.auto * 1.2` (orange) / `gc.auto * 1.5` (blue) / `gc.auto * 2` (purple) loose objects in the repo?

[image: Plot of the results]

Comment: That's great, thanks! The value 250 wasn't important, I was just trying to understand why it was not running. Could you point me to the file and line in the source where you found this? Thanks

Comment: Found it, `builtin/gc.c` in the function `too_many_loose_objects()`. it does `(gc_auto_threshold + 255) / 256` which for me would yield 1.97, rounding down to 1 if I remember how C integer division works. And it gc's when the number of loose objects in /17/ exceeds this value. With the default setting the count would need to exceed 28. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Could you tell me, how did you count this: *The chance that this happens is > 80% for 600 objects and > 90% for 800 objects.* ?

Comment: @codevolution If you assume that the first byte of sha-1 is uniformly distributed, you have a 1/256 chance that any given sha is in the folder in question. This then becomes in a binomial distribution and you can use any tool that can give you that CDF. I can only get WA to plot this at the moment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+CDF+Binomial%28+n%3D600,+p%3D1%2F256%29+with+x+in+0..4 You can see in the plot that P(X≤1) = 0.1 ⇒ P(X≥2) = 0.9.

Comment: @Chronial This type of info is enlightening. How did you collect the data for your chart? How did you create the chart? I'm not familiar with wolframalpha, other than knowing that it exists.

Comment: @GaTechThomas I used Matlab, which is a tool to do mathematical calculations. There I set up the formula for the probability and just ran that in a loop to get the value for each `gc.auto` value. I think I also created the chart in Matlab, but it's been a while ^^.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `gc auto` is be more robust in Git 2.12.2 (released March 2017, two days ago).

See [commit a831c06](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a831c06a2b639b0f862297672973bef965c7ffcd) (10 Feb 2017) by [David Turner (`csusbdt`)](https://github.com/csusbdt).
Helped-by: [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d30ec1b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d30ec1bece7f56080bac3e5a9f8dbc9f80508fdb), 21 Mar 2017)</sup>

> ### `gc`: ignore old `gc.log` files
>
> A server can end up in a state where there are lots of unreferenced loose objects (say, because many users are doing a bunch of rebasing and pushing their rebased branches).
>   Running "`git gc --auto`" in this state would cause a `gc.log` file to be created, preventing future auto gcs, causing pack files to pile up.
>   Since many git operations are `O(n)` in the number of pack files, this would lead to poor performance.
>
> Git should never get itself into a state where it refuses to do any maintenance, just because at some point some piece of the maintenance didn't make progress.
>
> **Teach Git to ignore `gc.log` files which are older than (by default)
>   one day old, which can be tweaked via the `gc.logExpiry` configuration
>   variable**.
>   That way, these pack files will get cleaned up, if necessary, at least once per day.  And operators who find a need for more-frequent gcs can adjust `gc.logExpiry` to meet their needs.

---

Note: since Git 2.17 (Q2 2018), `git gc --auto` will run on each `git commit` too.
See "[List of all commands that cause `git gc --auto`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49216495/6309)".

And there is a [`pre-gc --auto` hook associated to that command too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49330835/6309).

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:

```
git config --global gc.auto 0
```

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc/2.6.7