# Git reflog expiration time

Tags: git

I have known that reflog entries gets **deleted which are older than 90 days**. I have not made any change in git config too regarding this.
Today when I did `git reflog master --date=local`, I can see entries of 10 months before in it. How is that possible ?I should only be seeing entries dating back to 3 months before only ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git will automatically run `git gc` periodically, provided you don't disable it.  But the *period* for this automatic GC is not defined anywhere, and in fact, it's not based on time at all.  Instead, it's based on a quick survey that `git gc --auto` makes of the state of the repository.  Moreover, it's actually kicked off by running some other Git command, which simply runs `git gc --auto` at the end of its work.  That `git gc --auto` then decides whether to run `git gc`, and if so, that `git gc` runs `git reflog expire` with the 90 day expiration.

In this case, perhaps either you have not run a Git command that ran `git gc --auto`, or `git gc --auto` chose not to do anything, for 10 months.  That seems a bit excessive,<sup>1</sup> so it's more likely you disabled automatic GC by setting `gc.auto` to `0`.  It's also possible you have hit an interesting bug: see [this answer by VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43033037/1256452) to one of the "see also" questions below, which has a fix for a bug that did bite people.

See also [List of all commands that cause git gc --auto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5137447/1256452), [Understanding git gc --auto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16337498/1256452), and [How often should you use git-gc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55729/1256452)

---

<sup>1</sup>How excessive this is depends on how active the repository is.  A fairly quiet repo might not accumulate enough loose objects to make `git gc --auto` do anything for many months; a busy one will need automatic gc pretty frequently.

Answer (score 1):

> How is that possible?

Pretty simple explanation - that is possible if you don't run `git reflog expire` or `git gc` regularly. If you did that and they are still there, please amend your question. Else, that's it.

Type `git gc` and see them disappear.

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin, "I thought it is automatically done after 90 days ?" - it does not seem to happen in the pretty standard local dev repository I am using in my most active project right now; tried it before the answer, and yup, the reflogs were there. Not back up to the beginning of time, but about 5 months worth. I do not recall when I ran `git gc` in that respository last time, could well be that that was 5 months ago.